Ошибка при запуске приложения React
При запуске приложения на React+TS в контейнере Docker в терминале появляются следующие ошибки.
webts-1    | ReferenceError: document is not defined
webts-1    |     at ta (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:30849)
webts-1    |     at ts (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:30980)
webts-1    |     at /app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:33336
webts-1    |     at 8562 (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:33823)
webts-1    |     at Object.t [as require] (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
webts-1    |     at require (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18365)
webts-1    |     at I (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94362)
webts-1    |     at /app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:96668
webts-1    |     at F._fromJSON (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97106)
webts-1    |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) {
webts-1    |   digest: '2323993675'
webts-1    | }
webts-1    |    Generating static pages (1/4)
webts-1    |    Generating static pages (2/4)
webts-1    | 
webts-1    | Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
webts-1    | 
webts-1    | ReferenceError: document is not defined
webts-1    |     at ta (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:30849)
webts-1    |     at ts (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:30980)
webts-1    |     at /app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:33336
webts-1    |     at 8562 (/app/.next/server/app/page.js:28:33823)
webts-1    |     at Object.t [as require] (/app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
webts-1    |     at require (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18365)
webts-1    |     at I (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94362)
webts-1    |     at /app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:96668
webts-1    |     at F._fromJSON (/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97106)
webts-1    |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
webts-1    |    Generating static pages (3/4)
webts-1    |  ✓ Generating static pages (4/4)
webts-1    | 
webts-1    | > Export encountered errors on following paths:
webts-1    |    /page: /
webts-1 exited with code 1

В интернете нашел такие причины их появления, как нахождение лишних файлов/папок в папке page, но такой папки нет, так как Router от next не используется, и обращение к объекту document, но оно отсутствует в коде. Какая еще причина может быть?
Из ссылки  https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error не понятно что имеется ввиду: "Check for any code that assumes a prop is available, even when it might not be". Пропсы? Да используются.

Проблему решил, убрав "use client" из файла page.tsx.
